# Way to do array of enums in MariaDB?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, mariadb, sequelize.js

Is there way to make array of enums in MariaDB easy way?
I am using Sequelize in NodeJS. I need to save array of ENUM datatypes, but Sequelize documentation saying its possible only in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would you mind to provide the link to the _Sequelize_ documentation that says that ?

Comment: @TGrif Sure http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/data-types.js~ARRAY.html

Comment: @TGrif Same here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/data-types.html

Answer (score 0):

See the datatype `SET`.  It is essentially an `ENUM` for which a row can have more than one of the values set.  (We can discuss further if you provide a schema for context.)

Comment: Sorry but I dont see any datatype SET: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/data-types.html

Comment: MySQL's point of view:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set.html  I don't know about sequelizejs.

Answer (score -1):

ENUM works great with MariaDB (ARRAYS are different things):

example on how to use it :

```
  const MyObject = this.sequelize.define('_MyTABLE', {
    someCol: DataTypes.STRING,
    fruit: DataTypes.ENUM('pear', 'apple')
  });

  MyObject.create({ someCol: 'someValue', fruit: 'pear' }).then(...)
```

Comment: Sure but I am asking about ARRAY OF ENUMS